# why $\alpha ,\beta,\gamma$ :$(\beta + \gamma)\alpha = \beta\alpha + \beta \gamma$ doesn't hold?

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

this rule doesn't hold for all ordinals $\alpha  ,\beta,\gamma$ :$(\beta + \gamma)\alpha = \beta\alpha + \beta \gamma$.
I tested many examples but all of them holds for it !
does this hold ? $(B \cup C )\times A = (B \times A ) \cup(C\times A)$ for the their sets?
why the above rule doesn't hold ? please prove for me ! It hold for many finite and infinite sets I used !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a counter example:
$$(1+1) \cdot \omega = 2 \cdot \omega = \omega \neq \omega + \omega = \omega \cdot 2$$

- To see that $2 \cdot \omega = \omega$, recall that $2 \cdot \omega = \lim_{n < \omega} 2 \cdot n$. This is clearly equal to $\omega$.
- $\omega + \omega \neq \omega$ because there's an element $\alpha \in \omega + \omega$ that has an infinite number of elements less than $\alpha$. This doesn't happen in $\omega$.

Comment: oh,thank you so much , I tested this example but I thought $\omega.2 = \omega$ and $\omega +\omega = 2.\omega$ !now I find my mistake !